# How to calculate mean for each band in raster using GDAL and Python 3

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have a raster with 6 bands and I need to calculate the mean for all bands in the raster without value 0

I have this script but it works for one band only:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import ogr 

raster = gdal.Open("D:/script/NDVI2015.tif")
bands = raster.RasterCount
bands
6

geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
proj= raster.GetProjection()
data = raster.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
meandata(2) = np.mean(data[data != 0])#calcul mean without value 0
```

I'm very new with Python and GDAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @Luke's comment, incorporate the band number into a `for` loop using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

raster = gdal.Open(r'/path/to/your/image.tif')
bands = raster.RasterCount

for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
    mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
    print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))
```

Comment: what is 2 in last line  `print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))` ? ( mean,2)

Comment: @MajdaElyacouby I am just rounding to 2 decimal places using the Python function round().

Comment: your code is fonction for me and i have this result: `Band 1: Mean = 1712.83
Band 2: Mean = 1803.14
Band 3: Mean = 1662.33
Band 4: Mean = 1868.77
Band 5: Mean = 1900.97
Band 6: Mean = 2031.13` thank you , but please how can i save the value of mean for all bands in dataframe ?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: i need the value of mean for all bands next i want to save the value in dataframe for each bands$date and after i plot the datarame like timesseries with date in X and mean of values  for NDVI in axis y !

Comment: Are you after the mean of the individual band mean values? e.g. one mean value for each multiband raster?

Comment: no individuel mean value for one band  , i have 6 bands so i need 6 mean value like the résultats

Comment: I can update the answer to include how to write the mean band values to a list. However, I would recommend opening a new question on writing the mean values and year to a dataframe. Just ping me with the link to the new question and I would be happy to help.

Comment: the link for question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308876/the-mean-values-for-all-bands-and-date-to-a-dataframe

Comment: can i have some help to rastersize and do mask ? i don't know why i can't do mask with rasterio ?

Comment: @MajdaElyacouby This is beyond the scope of this question. Please open a new question.

Comment: yes i open i new question : if u can help thank u https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309180/cant-rastersize-shapefile-with-rasterio-and-gdal-give-0-value