# Calculate mean values for all bands and date to a dataframe

Tags: python, modis, ndvi, data-frame, pandas

I have 5 rasters, each having 10 bands, where each band corresponds to a specific date.

How do I calculate mean values for all 10 bands and save them?

I need to save the mean values in a dataframe like this example:

```
   rasters   bands       mean         date             years 
    raster1   band1       1234         24/01/2000       2000
              band2       45213        01/03/2000       2000
              band3        4221        12/04/2000       2000 
              band4         ...         ...              ....
              band10
   raster 2   band 1       4521        01/02/2001      2001
              band2        1234        04/05/2001      2001
              ...           ....         ....
```

This script calculates mean value for each band in my raster:

```
raster = gdal.Open("D:/script/NDVI2000.tif")
bands = raster.RasterCount

for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
    mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
    print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))
Out[2]:
Band 1: Mean = 1712.83
Band 2: Mean = 1803.14
Band 3: Mean = 1662.33
Band 4: Mean = 1868.77
Band 5: Mean = 1900.97
Band 6: Mean = 2031.13
Band 7: Mean = 1847.89
Band 8: Mean = 2185.66
Band 9: Mean = 2081.14
Band 10: Mean = 8248.7
```

How can I save the mean result stats in the dataframe using gdal python 3 after I have the results for all rasters?

I need this dataframe to plot times series for NDVI.

Comment: Where does the `date` data come from in your output example?

Comment: How are you acquiring the date and year information? How do you hope to incorporate time into the dataframe?

Comment: @Aaron before doing rasterstack in ENVI i hade the bands with date ( one bands for one date ) exemple : MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001 first band for julianday 209 = 01/07/2000 so  i'm doing srack for all bands in the same years with ordre just in ENVI 5.2 cause i don't know how doing stack in gdal Python 3 and how to export the date from name of band to dataframe

Comment: @Aaron i know the date for all bands in all rasters so just need to add date in dataframe i think !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, append dicts to an empty list. It seems from your example output, you may want to do this inside a function that you can pass the path of the target raster. Note the `???` means you will have to implement something. Maybe your year comes from the filename?

```py
import pandas as pd

raster_filename = "D:/script/NDVI2000.tif"
raster = gdal.Open(raster_filename)
bands = raster.RasterCount

row_list = []

for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
    mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
    row_list.append({
        'raster': os.path.basename(raster_filename),
        'band': band,
        'mean': mean,
        'year': ???,
        'date': ???,
        })
    print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))

# create DataFrame with columns from the dict keys
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
df.to_csv('band_means.csv')
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank u for answer i will test it and undersant  and if i want to do it for 5 rasters ( 10 bans in the rasters ) and all the raster in the same folder NDVI2000, NDVI2001 , NDVI2003 ,...

Comment: I'd recommend Python's `os.scandir()` to loop over the files

Comment: i will try it sincerly cause i need to undersan thank u

Comment: `date': ???` i don't know how can writhe  `date:01/02/2000`

Comment: `date : 01-02-2000    ^
SyntaxError: invalid token`

Comment: You might try [Pandas to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) it is very flexible on the input that it will parse

Comment: @vpipt need some help to use os.scandir()  please  to do the same thing for all raster in the same folder  i can't do it !!! thank u for help

Comment: need some help to use os.scandir() please to loop over the files ( all raster in the same folder)  i can't do it !!! thank u for help

Comment: @MajdaElyacouby stack overflow has a tonne of help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python/52298436#52298436
Also don't forget the very good documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

Comment: yes thank u for doc  for os.scandir is not easy i m trying but not work wth os.scandir

Comment: `os.listdir()` is a little simpler to use. it returns a list of strings. Useful if you can make simplifying assumptions about the directory contents, such as contains only files, no symlinks, etc.