# Calculate mean for each band in raster

Tags: raster, gdal, band, mean

I'd like to re-visit this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308767/how-to-calculate-mean-for-each-band-in-raster-using-gdal-and-python-3) given by Aaron that uses `gdal` and `numpy` to calculate the mean value of each band.

Issue 1: With large TIFFs ~ 5-15GB, I am running into a memory error. I am wondering if gdal is uncompressing the TIFF and making it explode?

Issue 2: I switched to a lower resolution and it does run, but the results are different comparing to what QGIS gives in the layer properties. I tired calculating with and without the zero's, but still no match. With zero's is closer, but is still off by about 3 units.

I understand that larger TIFFs will take a bit longer to processes, but it seems faster to plop them into QGIS and get the values from there. Trying to find a "just as fast" automated solution.

I am open to using `rasterio`, `Tiffile`, or other raster libraries.

```
def rgb(ortho):
    raster = gdal.Open(ortho)
    bands = raster.RasterCount

    for band in range(1, bands + 1):
        data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('int')
        mean = np.mean(data[data != 0])  # calculate mean without value 0
        print("Band %s: Mean = %s" % (band, round(mean, 2)))
```

**Output:**

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 42.1 GiB for an array with shape (90880, 62208) and data type float64
```

**QGIS Mean Properties:**

[image]

**Python Output with zero's:**

[image]

**Python Output without zero's**

[image]

Comment: Try `gdalinfo -stats`?  Either parsing the output from the command line util, or maybe you can hit that via the python bindings

Comment: With Python use GetStatistics. A full example in https://thegeoict.com/blog/2020/08/12/getting-the-statistics-of-raster-with-gdal/.

Comment: @user30184, yes that does work and works with the bigger TIFFs (at the moment), but it is still incredibly slow.

Comment: Tried a TIFF ~6GB. Took 6 minutes.

Comment: If you want to get accurate statistics you must read every pixel. Gdalinfo supports faster approximated statistics but I do not know how to use it with Python. Perhaps with gdal.Info and InfoOptions https://gdal.org/python/index.html if you want to try.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll go ahead and read through this and try some other ways. I just find it odd that it is faster to find it manually through QGIS.

Comment: `GetStatistics(int approx_ok, int force)` so the following should be a bit quicker (`approx_ok` means to sample the raster to calculate the stats) -  `min, max, mean, stddev = raster.GetRasterBand(band).GetStatistics(1, 1)`

Comment: There seems to be `STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES` in the QGIS screenshot that you attached. That may explain both the good speed and the difference to the results that you obtained with the numpy method that reads all pixels.

Comment: Isn't the whole point to get exact statistics? By using the approximated statistics flag you're getting to the wrong answer faster. 15GB isn't particularly large and if they're compressed you can bet your CPU is at max for 1-2 cores but your HDD is barely being tickled, try multi-threading with one process for each core using subprocess popen redirecting stdout to a unique text file per process, it will still take a long time but you'll have many results over the same interval. Are you sure the type is int64, ortho is usually byte, that would help your memory problem.

Comment: That is correct @MichaelStimson. I was messing around with the data type and forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all the helpful comments and some additional troubleshooting, here is what I found:

QGIS is treating the NaN values (pixels that fall within the extent of the ortho, but are not actually in the ortho - see image) as zeros. So my band averages are darker (closer to zero) then they should be. I sectioned my ortho into multiple pieces and disregarded the sections that contained the edges (for testing purposes) and compared the values from both the original code I posted and from the [link](https://thegeoict.com/blog/2020/08/12/getting-the-statistics-of-raster-with-gdal/) user30184 provided to how QGIS calculated their average values and they were negligible.

I also compared the highest res image to a lower res image and found that for my purposes, the mean values were negligible (max difference of around 0.5 units). So for my purpose, I will stick to using the lower res ortho.

Final code:

```
def rgb_mean(output)
    rgb_df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'])
    raster = gdal.Open(output)
    bands = raster.RasterCount
    avg = []

    for band in range(1, bands + 1):
        data = raster.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray()
        mean = np.mean(data)
        avg.append(mean)

    rgb_df = rgb_df.append({'Red': avg[0], 'Green': avg[1], 'Blue': avg[2]}, ignore_index=True)
```

I removed the `[data != 0]` from `mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]` because I do want to include pixels that may have a zero in their band.

[image]

Comment: Float (32) is the same memory space as int (32), double (64) uses the same memory as int64, both are overkill from a byte data type. Use the GDAL pixel type constants to determine the number of bytes (data type) to use per pixel so you're not wasting memory or degrading your data. In this case I would read in blocks accumulating the values and counting the number of non-nodata values and then divide. Eventually you're going to have a size of a band in uncompressed bytes that is larger than your available RAM and end up thrashing your pagefile which could explain why it's so slow

Comment: QGIS and GDAL would leave the NaN values out from the statistics if the value was labeled as nodata. If that was the case then the QGIS image into would show the nodata value in section "bands" and STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT would be less than 100. You can fix your image with for example gdal_edit.py and assign the nodata value.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I printed my data type `print(gdal.GetDataTypeName(data.DataType))` and found it to be byte. To clarify, I can remove `.astype('float')`?

Comment: Yes, it should be safe to omit, if you have any problems use astype('byte') to assert the type rather than convert the type.